# Nodejs calling function from within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have 3 methods

```
exports.getImageById = function (resultFn, id) {
 ...
}

exports.getCollectionById = function (resultFn, id) {
}
```

in the third method I want to call both methods

```
exports.getCollectionImages = function (resultFn, collectionId) {

var arr = new Array();

this.getCollectionById(   // fine, 1st call
    function (result) {
        var images = result.image;
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            this.getImageById(function (result1) {   // error, 2nd call
                    arr[i] = result1;
                }, images[i]
            );

         }
    }
    , collectionId
);

resultFn(arr);
}
```

I can call first function `this.getCollectionById` but it fails to call `this.getImageById`, it says undefined function, whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `this.getCollectionById` passing it a callback, the callback doesn't have access to the same `this`

The simplest solution is to save `this` as a local variable.

```
exports.getCollectionImages = function (resultFn, collectionId) {    
    var arr = new Array();        
    var me = this; // Save this
    this.getCollectionById(   // fine, 1st call
        function (result) {
            var images = result.image;
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                // Use me instead of this
                me.getImageById(function (result1) {   // error, 2nd call
                    arr[i] = result1;
                }, images[i]);
            }
        }, collectionId);
    resultFn(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems that javascript is pure instance oriented language

Comment: A more accurate description is that methods in JavaScript are not bound to an instance, it depends on how they are called.

Comment: @sleimanjneidi is your `getImageById` asynchronous? If so, the value of `i` will be wrong  (the last value of i in the loop) in the callback to `me.getImageById`

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` inside the inner function is not the same object as outside, because it's determined depending on how the function is called. You can find a detailed explanation in the [MDN article on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

One of the ways to solve it is by keeping a reference to the outer `this` in another variable such as `that`:

```
var that = this;
this.getCollectionById(   // fine, 1st call
    function (result) {
        var images = result.image;
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            that.getImageById(function (result1) {   // 2nd call
                    arr[i] = result1;
                }, images[i]
            );

        }
    }
    , collectionId
);
```