# Access RemoveListener Function from Another Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Javascript and got some errors. I can't figure out how to fix it.

I am adding a listener in here. I tried to add 'exports.' for access.

```
function AddListenerToBot(ChannelName)
{
    var CommandsListener = function Commands(from,message)
    {
        //snip
    }

    exports.CommandsListener = CommandsListener;

    bot.addListener('MessageCH'+ChannelName.toLowerCase(),CommandsListener);

}
```

It is working but when I need to remove it from another functions, I get an error

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

I can't access it.

Here is the removing function. They are in the same .js file.

```
 exports.RemoveListenerFroMBot = function(IncomingCommandText, CBValue)
    {  
            //snip
                        if (err)
                        {
                            console.log('Error', err);
                            CBValue('Error');
                        }
                        else
                        {
  bot.removeListener('IncomingCommandText.toLowerCase()',AddListenerToBot.CommandsListener);
                            console.log('Success');
                            CBValue('success);
                        }       
                    //snip
    }
```

Can someone help me to how can i remove listener from another function?

I looked them and can't find anything; 
[Node.js EventEmitter: How to bind a class context to the event listener and then remove this listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820651/node-js-eventemitter-how-to-bind-a-class-context-to-the-event-listener-and-then) 
[Nodejs calling function from within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768764/nodejs-calling-function-from-within-a-function) 
[node.js event listener in another source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155249/node-js-event-listener-in-another-source-file) 
[How do I properly remove an event listener within a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036579/how-do-i-properly-remove-an-event-listener-within-a-class) 
[removeEventListener of Anonymous function javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229560/removeeventlistener-of-anonymous-function-javascript) 
[Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working) 
[Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Edit1:**
That's the Add function that using AddListenerBot() function.

```
exports.Add = function(ComingCB, cb)
{
        //snip
                    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(JSONData)
                    fs.writeFile('./Database/Ch.json', jsonString, err =>
                    {
                        if (err)
                        {
                            console.log('Err', err);
                            cb('Err');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('Success');
                            cb('Success');
                            AddListenerToBot(ComingCB);                       
                        }
                    })
        //snip          
}
```

Comment: even if what you were trying to do made sense, ` exports.CommandsListener = CommandsListener;` isn't executed until `AddListenerToBot` is executed ... so the export couldn't happen until too late

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do you think should i move that exports after adding listener?

Comment: how would that work, since `CommandsListener` is defined inside `AddListenerToBot` ... I'm sure adding/removing listeners isn't that difficult - I just can't figure out what you're trying to do

Comment: In another function called Add(IncommingCommand,CBValue), i am getting parameters and do things in code then execute AddListenerToBot(param1,param2) function depends on the parameters from Add() function. Then get the values for using them in the CommandsListener function. After everything is finished i add listener to bot with function to work is proper. If its bad practice coding, can you help me to fix it?

Comment: I edited the post. Added the Add() function for better explanation.

Comment: In the the `bot.removeListener` call you reference `AddListenerToBot.CommandsListener`, but you don't seem to have defined that anywhere. Are you misunderstanding `exports`?

Comment: Could be, what i was trying to do is CommandsListener function to make global in that file. So i thought that i can access it from anywhere (for example in bot.removeListener). I read some things about 'exports'. I thought that they were like make the functions global.

Comment: No, `exports` is used to export from the file, so try changing it to `AddListenerToBot.CommandsListener = CommandsListener;`.